# Passing parameter from config to hivescript

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to pass parameters from a config file to shell script and assign it to local parameter as shown below and then pass the local parameter to hive script. 
The basic structure is shown below. However the source columns names are not reflected in the final table. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
#passing values from config to shell and  source_file_name is a runtime parameter#####
if [ ${source_file_name}=tab_1 ];
 then 
  ${source_table}=tab_1 ${source_columns_names}=tab1_columns 
fi 

nohup hive -f /hivescript.hql -hivevar source_columns_names=${source_columns} -hivevar source_table_name=${source_table}

#######config file values#####
tab_1= table_one_name tab1_columns=table_one_columns
```

enter code here

Comment: Have you tried replacing -hivevar with -hiveconf or --hiveconf?  That is the argument name that has always worked for me.

Comment: Variable ${source_columns}  used in command expression "... -hivevar source_columns_names=${source_columns}" is not assigned.